# Find and replace Img tag in a string via php?

Tags: php, regex

Find and replace Img tag in a string via php ?

```
$source = "<img src='source.jpg'>";
$dest = '<div id="pf1" class="pf w0 h0" data-page-no="1">
<div class="pc pc1 w0 h0">
  <img class="bi x0 y0 w0 h0" alt="" src="../images/cover.jpg"/>
</div>';
```

I want to replace that `$source` image in `$dest` image ..

Comment: Check - https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function, 2 of 3 arguments you already have, the *pattern* could be like `'/<img(.*?)\/>/'`:

```
$find = '/<img(.*?)\/>/';
$source = '<img src="source.jpg">';
$dest = '<div id="pf1" class="pf w0 h0" data-page-no="1">
<div class="pc pc1 w0 h0">
  <img class="bi x0 y0 w0 h0" alt="" src="../images/cover.jpg"/>
</div>';

echo preg_replace($find, $source, $dest);
```

Output will be:

```
<div id="pf1" class="pf w0 h0" data-page-no="1">
<div class="pc pc1 w0 h0">
  <img src="source.jpg">
</div>
```

[Working demo](https://3v4l.org/6CYQU)

Comment: It is generally not recommended to use regex's to manipulate HTML as the chances of it breaking are quite high.

Comment: @NigelRen, perhaps, but in case of using a little parts of it - chances are much less.

Comment: Difficulties become when this is just a small part of a full web page and the same code is used, then people start using it for other tags and the chances increase.

Comment: @NigelRen, have had read an opinion about RegEx in your "marked" post, yeap, need to be sure how does manipulation affects on your HTML during of using it. That's should be a rule for eachone who use it. Honestly, I'm never using this in my projects. I don't like render HTML via PHP at all.